# I want to make my PC a gateway

Tags: gateway, adsl

Following is my current network diagram:
[image]

The diagram explains itself. The modem is connected to the internet by a ADSL phone line which also contains a landline phone.

I want to add a gateway after the modem so that I can filter the data, how do I do that?

If I tell my modem to use my gateway as the default gateway (which is just a PC with two standard NIC's), how will I connect it to the telephone line?

Comment: Making a gateway **for Internet access** is easy. Put the new `GatewayDesktop` after the modem, plug one NIC into the ADSL modem and one into the internal network. Set the default gateway from this PC to the modems IP. Set the default GW for the internal computers to your GatewayPC.  However telephony comes nowhere into play. If you have old fashioned non-mobile telephones then leave them plugged in as they were.

Comment: Note that this assumes that you turn of wireless in the ADSL-modem/switch/router/WAP combo device. If you want to use a desktop PC as sole router, then provice that wireless service by the desktop.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to leave the setup as is and only logically route everything via your PC (and thus not providing hard security), then please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/980651/edit) the question to reflect that.

Comment: Actually, if you google `turn linux pc into gateway router`, you will hit many guides to do excatly what you wish to do. Keep in mind that, in order to provide WiFi services, you will also need to install and configure `hostapd`, which not all of the above guides mention. For this you may either use your pc onboard wifi card, or buy a USB dongle to dedicate to this aim.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae The problem is that my PC does not run linux, it runs Windows.

Comment: Then I do not believe it is possible at all, sorry.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Why?

Comment: If you're going to dedicate a machine to be a gateway, then the salient point is "dedicate". You no longer want to be using it as a regular desktop, so it doesn't matter what OS it runs, so long as it does the intended task. cake ≠ eat it. Plan as modem > gateway/router > internal distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to separate functions, you have to replace the modem-router with a modem and a router:

- The modem will connect to ADSL and to the first NIC of the gateway.
- The second NIC of the gateway will go to the router (LAN+Wireless) which will provide the connectivity to the users.

In that way, all the data traffic will pass through the gateway where you can inspect it, filter it, ban it... whatever.